# Why is my matplotlibanimation not plotting on tkinter?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, tkinter, matplotlib-animation

I am trying to animate stock prices from a `csv` file on a `matplotlib` graph and embed this onto `tkinter`. The issue is that I can't seem to get it to work with `tkinter`.

The issue I am having is that it only shows a `matplotlib` graph on the `tkinter` window without anything on it as shown on the image.

Output:

[image: Output]

When I run a split terminal and run my other script to generate the prices and another script to animate this using just `matplotlib` and no `tkinter` it works, but whenever I try to add it to a `tkinter` window it doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, animation
import pandas as pd

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Embed Animation to Tkinter frame")

fig = plt.Figure(dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot([], [])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    x = data['x_value']
    price = data['stock_price']
    line.set_data(x, price)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
tkinter.mainloop()
```

I have watched countless videos on `matplotlib` animations on `tkinter`, and I cannot seem to figure out why it isn't working.

Contents of the `csv` file:

[image: contents of the csv file]

Answer (score 0):

There might be not coded with plot options.
Try with adding the below code:

```
line=plt.plot(variable, variable, color='skyblue', marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=6)[0]
```